# Hide API Key in JQuery Web Application

Tags: jquery

I've written a simple API for a web service (or database). The API provides SQL like functions such as select, update and delete. A client has to send an API key in order to use the API. I'm going to write native clients (in C++/Java) for different OSes, however I'd like to create a web client first.

I could write this web application in PHP, however in my opinion this isn't state of the art (for example you have to retrieve the whole web page after you submitted a form). Due to this I'd like to use JQuery. And here comes the problem how can I restrict the access of my API to certain clients? Users could easily analyze my JQuery code to in order to find the the API key and command.

Comment: Implement it in PHP and use AJAX.

Comment: And how can I assure that a user uses the web frontend to send his or her POST requests and not some curl spammer script? (without a logic which checks if a request makes sense)

Comment: Require user authentication.